# Show that the set $S = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_1^2 + x_2^2 = x_3^2, (x_1, x_2, x_3) + (0,0,0)\}$ is not connected

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

This problem is in my text:

> In $R^3$ with the Euclidean metric, show that the set $S = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_1^2 + x_2^2 = x_3^2, (x_1, x_2, x_3) + (0,0,0)\}$ is not connected.

I'm stuck on the $(x_1, x_2, x_3) + (0,0,0)$ part of the definition of $S$.
This notation doesn't make sense because its not a condition.

Ignoring that part, $S$ would be a conic surface, which would be connected. So what does  $(x_1, x_2, x_3) + (0,0,0)$ mean?

Comment: It's most probably a typo. The one thing that I can think the authors meant and makes most sense is $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \neq (0, 0, 0).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be a typo, the only thing I can think of that makes any sort of sense would be the condition
$$ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \neq (0,0,0). $$